# expo result: the development server returned response error code:500

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo, vscode-debugger

I am working on my react native project where I am connecting vs code terminal to that expo app but after many trials, getting the same error even though i dont have any duplicate files.

Getting this error:

```
Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
    at setModule (D:\First React Native Project\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\index.js:510:17) 
    at workerReply (D:\First React Native Project\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\index.js:570:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 9)
    at async D:\First React Native Project\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\index.js:344:18
    at async DependencyGraph.ready (D:\First React Native Project\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:99:5)
    at async Bundler.ready (D:\First React Native Project\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:69:5)
    at async IncrementalBundler.ready (D:\First React Native Project\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\IncrementalBundler.js:287:5)    
    at async Server.ready (D:\First React Native Project\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1228:5)
```